# JS : How can iframe2 change the src of iframe1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my HTML source:

```
<body>
<iframe id='iframe1' src="http://site1.com/myScript.html"></iframe>
<iframe id='iframe2' src="http://site2.com"></iframe>
</body>
```

How can I (in myScript.html page) change the src of iframe ?
(or navigate to site3.com)

myScript.html;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
<script>
function navigateIFrame2() {
// code to change the url or navigate iframe2
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can't. Iframes in different domains can't access each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#iframe2', window.parent.document).attr("src" "new url");
```

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you didn't explain the code. If you do explain it (in your answer), you are far more likely to get more upvotes—and the questioner is more likely to learn something!

Comment: are the iframes on the same website? I missed a comma, between src and new url too.

Comment: No: as I said: site1.com and site2.com, but both CAN be EMBEDDED into frames (no x-origin security of site1, site2, site3)

Comment: Add a ALLOW-FROM header on site2 that allows site 1 access